# I want to fetch & show only a text status update, how could I specify this in my script?

Tags: jquery, post, fetch, facebook-page

Dear fellow programmers,

I am working on my B&B's website www.bordemundo.com and would like to include my very latest facebook pages status update in the header of my website.

As I am not a crack when it comes to JQuery I ran Google and edited a script which works just fine. I managed to get rid of the date-stamp that I actually do not need, as the status would change exactly once a day. Now I noticed that it does also update when I share another page's friend's phot album or any link or digital information.

I would rather only fetch the status updates that I type in myself. Has anyone of you an idea how I could easily manage this by using the script that I edited? I attached the code below.

Thx for considering and I really appreciate any help!

```
(function($) {
$.fn.faceFeed = function(options) {
    /**
     * Configuration
     *
     * `pageName:` The name of your Facebook page. Required.
     * `tokenGenerator:` Path to a file that will return a JSON access_token. If defined, this will take
     *                   priority over `accessToken`.
     * `accessToken:` A token you generate at <https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer>.
     * `dateClass:` The class of the `<span>` that contains your date "ago in words". Default: `post-date`
     */
    var config = {
        pageName:    '',
        tokenGenerator: '', // default: token.php
        accessToken: '',
        postsToFetch: 1
    };
    $.fn.extend(config, options);

    /**
     * Converts "http://" links into <a> tags.
     *
     * @param {String} a block of text for which all "http://" links need conversion
     * @return {String} the same block of text with URLs re-formatted.
     */
    function linkify(text){
        if (text) {
            text = text.replace(
                /((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)(\w{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/gi,
                function(url){
                    var full_url = url;
                    if (!full_url.match('^https?:\/\/')) {
                        full_url = 'http://' + full_url;
                    }
                    return '<a href="' + full_url + '">' + url + '</a>';
                }
            );
        }
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * Requests your page's status feed from the Open Graph and injects it as HTML into the
     * element.
     *
     * @param {String} accessToken - A generated or provided access token for authorizing
     *                               with the API.
     */
    function getPosts(accessToken, self) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+config.pageName+'/feed',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                access_token: accessToken,
                limit: config.postsToFetch
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                self.html('');
                for (var c=0; c < response.data.length; c++) {
                    var status = response.data[c];
                    var statusMessage = (status.message) ? status.message : status.story;

                    var txt = linkify(statusMessage);

                    var row = $('<span class="status"></span>').html(txt);
                    self.append(row);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /*
     * Runtime.
     */
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.html('<p>Lade Neuigkeiten...</p>');

        if (config.tokenGenerator) {
            $.ajax({
                url: config.tokenGenerator,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(generator) {
                    getPosts(generator.access_token, self);
                }
            })
        } else {
            getPosts(config.accessToken, self);
        }
    });
};
```

})(jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change from reading the page feed to reading page statuses.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You can also be sure the poster of the item is who you want it to be by checking each item's post.from.id and ensuring that ID is the ID of the poster you want to display

Comment: Dude, thx a lot. I understand these two options at least logically. Unf. I am not kind of a programmer but anyways, I will read the link provided and maybe get an idea! THANK YOU!

Comment: Dude, I soooooo much owe you. By simply changing this line "url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+config.pageName+'/feed'," to "url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+config.pageName+'/statuses'," it works like a charme. The only things pulled actually seem to be the things I type into the box. You really made my day. I can't push you the point you earn. Keeps telling me I need 15 other points in the forum. From time to time I raise questions here and as soon as I can you will be rewarded! Saludos desde Puerto Varas, compadre!

Comment: Yeah, you really were. I like this feature for my b&b's site pretty much. I donÄt like these weather plugins out there as they are all kind of crappy, slow and ugly. So I thought to myself: who's the best weather frog if not me, I am sitting right at Lake Llanquihue's shoreline anyways. So I tell the people out there what weather we have.

Comment: So then I thought on which source to rely. Well, in fact I pretty much do all stuff on Facebook group for Bordemundo. So now that I differ between feed actions and status posts i can simply update my weather once a day in the morning and the people can read it fresh from the press on bordemundo.com. AWESOME, wouldn't have gotten there without you, I read a lot but simply overlooked that.

Comment: Now I look for a possibility to show the exact puerto varas time when user opens the website to signalize the timely validity of the post. when i managed i will provide you a link here. Gracias!

Comment: So, here we go. That's the example. The script shows only the last Status update in the top middle! http://www.bordemundo.com/index.html